# What are good Lazarus/FPC Resources?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I want to learn to develop applications in Lazarus, but I need resources, preferably books, to Lazarus.

Keep in mind that I know 0 of Pascal.
Thanks.

Comment: [Object Pascal Tutorial](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Object_Pascal_Tutorial), [Lazarus Tutorial](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Tutorial). As you proceed look for more documentation in the site, like: [Object Oriented Programming with FreePascal and Lazarus](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Object_Oriented_Programming_with_FreePascal_and_Lazarus), [Programming Using Objects](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Programming_Using_Objects). As you can see there's plenty of documentation on http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org :). Not sure you'll be able to find any books..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Lazarus - The Complete Guide** can be  found **[here](http://www.blaisepascal.eu/index.php?actie=./subscribers/lazarusbookinfoEnglish)**.

**UPDATE**:

- http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Tutorial
- http://wiki.freepascal.org/Howdy_World_%28Hello_World_on_steroids%29
- http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Documentation
- http://wiki.freepascal.org/Pascal_and_Lazarus_Books_and_Magazines

Free book is **[here](http://freepascalanswers.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/freepascallazarus-book-startprog)**. I know **[this](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk)** is for Delphi but it will also help a Lazarus newbie very much.

To my knowledge there are also books in german (paid), portuguese (paid), and arabic (free).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler and non visual manuals are [here](http://www.freepascal.org/docs.var)

One can also use Delphi resources to some degree; [Essential Pascal](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/) is also always a good read, and so are the older Mastering Delphi books from the same author

Answer (score 1):

Marco Cantu's book "Essential Pascal" is a good, implementation agnostic Pascal guide for the Object Pascal dialects of Pascal (Lazarus, FPC, Delphi).
http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/
An older version of the book is available free, and the most recent can be purchased.

Answer (score 0):

I learned using the book

> 'Oh! Pascal!'

.  Clear and basic - very good.